# gfortran: Symbol 'grid' has no IMPLICIT type

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran95

I'm making a tic tac toe program with a 2D array of characters in a 3x3 shape to hold all the spots on the grid. I've disabled implicit typing with `implicit none`, but I get errors about my array not having an implicit type.

```
program tictactoe
  ! No implicit typing, e
  implicit none
  ! Welcome banner
  print *, "Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!"
  ! Initialize grid as a 2D array
  character, dimension(3:3, 3:3) :: grid
  ! Fill grid with blank spaces
  grid = reshape( (/ ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' /), (/ 3, 3 /))
end program tictactoe
```

```
tac.f95:12:40:

   12 |   character, dimension(3:3, 3:3) :: grid
      |                                        1
Error: Unexpected data declaration statement at (1)
tac.f95:14:6:

   14 |   grid = reshape( (/ ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' /), (/ 3, 3 /))
      |      1
Error: Symbol ‘grid’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
```

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong? Your help is greatly appreciated.

GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 9.2.1-9ubuntu2) 9.2.1 20191008, Ubuntu Budgie 19.10 amd64

Comment: You cannot declare a type after an executablle statement. We shouod have a duplicate. Always check the first error message, not the last one.

Comment: BTW, welcome, I suggest to take the [tour].